# Rearrange simple associated products in configurable product options

Tags: magento-1.8, configurable-product, product-association

I want to rearrange simple associated products in configurable products.
See attached screen-shot.
[image: product association]

In frontend and here in admin-end also product with 15 oz is coming first then 8 oz. 
But now what I want is to show Option 8 oz first then option 15 oz 
Please let me know how can I achieve this and how Magento is arranging this options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just go to Manage your attribute "Size", there are position in Manage Label/Options, give them position ordering. for your situation you can give 8 for 8oz, 15 for 15oz, and that will order correctly.

Comment: I guess, this is really a stupid question from me. How can I miss this?

Comment: everyone would make some mistakes sometimes ;)